# Is there an analog to ArcGIS Area Solar Radiation in R?

Tags: r, solar-radiation

Is there a function in R to compute direct, diffuse, and global insolation based of DEM in R similar to Area Solar Radiation tool in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two R analogues to the Area Solar Radiation model in ArcGIS are the "[solaR](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/solar/)" Perpiñán (2012) and "[insol](http://www.meteoexploration.com/R/insol/index.html)" packages however, these are not implementations of the Fu & Rich (2002) algorithms. Since the Fu & Rich (2002) algorithm uses slope and aspect to build a sky mask to pass sun tracks though at each time step, it really is the *de facto* standard for spatial solar insolation estimates. I believe that the insol package will account for parallax but not actual topography.

[Fu, P., & P.M. Rich (2002) A geometric solar radiation model with applications in agriculture and forestry. *Computers and Electronics in Agriculture* 37:25-35](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/14e3/eb7b8f32ea3cc91ca2c65550106ac4998942.pdf)

[Perpiñán, O. (2012) solaR: Solar Radiation and Photovoltaic Systems with R, Journal of Statistical Software, 50(9):1-32.](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v050i09)